# Is there a way to fail a C# compile on XSD warnings?

Tags: c#, xsd

I have been gradually replacing very large text file lookups with XSD validated XML lookups that provide basic validation like making sure there are no duplicate values or invalid values.

I want to make the compile fail if a developer enters data on the XML that violates the key constraint.

I have set my projects to treat warnings as errors and I do get warnings at compile time for the key constraint violations, but the compile still completes successfully.

Is there a way to make the compile fail so that developers are forced to fix the conflict?

Comment: eeee.... suggest you try Nant or MSBuild for these kind of things.